# Inability to connect to Yarn leads to infinite loop in retries

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using a Yarn EMR cluster through AWS. I am trying to write some tests for my codebase to ensure that I have test coverage for a Yarn connection.

Right now I am purposely making my connection fail by messing with the variable `YARN_CONF_DIR`. If the variable is set properly, I can connect to Yarn with no issue and run my job. However, when `YARN_CONF_DIR` is set but not to a path that has the expected xml, cfg, and bash files, I get the following output:

```
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Now, I expected an error, of course. The weird thing is that you can see that the number of retries is looping, which I find odd. Look at the part of each line that says `Already tried (x) time(s)` and you can see it goes `0,1,2,3...9,0,1,2,3...9,0,1`. I figured after retry #9 it would simply error and yield some sort of `connection refused` error. Instead, I am stuck in an infinite loop.

The command I am running is:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster simple_spark_app_test.py
```

I also tried setting `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts` to be 10 explicitly, but it doesn't affect the infinite looping. E.g. the command looked like

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=10 simple_spark_app_test.py
```

Please note this only occurs if `YARN_CONF_DIR` is set but not to the right directory. If it is not set at all then it gives me an error that `YARN_CONF_DIR` must be set, as I would expect.